# Find the day of a week

Tags: r, date, r-faq

Let's say that I have a date in R and it's formatted as follows.

```
   date      
2012-02-01 
2012-02-01
2012-02-02
```

Is there any way in R to add another column with the day of the week associated with the date? The dataset is really large, so it would not make sense to go through manually and make the changes.

```
df = data.frame(date=c("2012-02-01", "2012-02-01", "2012-02-02"))
```

So after adding the days, it would end up looking like:

```
   date       day
2012-02-01   Wednesday
2012-02-01   Wednesday
2012-02-02   Thursday
```

Is this possible? Can anyone point me to a package that will allow me to do this?
Just trying to automatically generate the day by the date.

Comment: somewhat related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16193549/how-can-i-create-a-vector-containing-the-days-of-the-week

Answer (score 363, accepted):

```
df = data.frame(date=c("2012-02-01", "2012-02-01", "2012-02-02")) 
df$day <- weekdays(as.Date(df$date))
df
##         date       day
## 1 2012-02-01 Wednesday
## 2 2012-02-01 Wednesday
## 3 2012-02-02  Thursday
```

**Edit:** Just to show another way...

The `wday` component of a `POSIXlt` object is the numeric weekday (0-6 starting on Sunday).

```
as.POSIXlt(df$date)$wday
## [1] 3 3 4
```

which you could use to subset a character vector of weekday names

```
c("Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", 
    "Friday", "Saturday")[as.POSIXlt(df$date)$wday + 1]
## [1] "Wednesday" "Wednesday" "Thursday"
```

Comment: +1 Is there a way to use `weekdays` to get the number of weekday as you do using `as.POSIXlt`??

Comment: @Shambho I guess you could do this: `setNames(0:6, c("Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"))[weekdays(as.Date(df$date))]`.  If you don't like the names, you could wrap `unname()` around it.

Comment: To get the weekday number (0-6,Sun-Sat) from the date you can do: format(as.Date(df$date),"%w") . For the format code details see http://www.stat.berkeley.edu/~s133/dates.html

Answer (score 99):

Use the `lubridate` package and function `wday`:

```
library(lubridate)
df$date <- as.Date(df$date)
wday(df$date, label=TRUE)
[1] Wed   Wed   Thurs
Levels: Sun < Mon < Tues < Wed < Thurs < Fri < Sat
```

Comment: The good thing about this approach is that it returns the days as a factor, so if you create a chart the days will be in the correct order.

Comment: To get the full word for each day (e.g. Sunday instead of Sun): `abbr = FALSE`

Answer (score 79):

Look up `?strftime`:

> `%A` Full weekday name in the current locale

```
df$day = strftime(df$date,'%A')
```

Comment: In case somebody searched for a weekday number - use `'%u'` instead of `'%A'`

Comment: If you want the numerical day of the week, don't forget to use the original Date object, not the strftime result because it's of type character

Answer (score 18):

Let's say you additionally want the week to begin on **Monday** (instead of default on Sunday), then the following is helpful:

```
require(lubridate)
df$day = ifelse(wday(df$time)==1,6,wday(df$time)-2)
```

The result is the days in the interval [0,..,6].

If you want the interval to be [1,..7], use the following:

```
df$day = ifelse(wday(df$time)==1,7,wday(df$time)-1)
```

... or, alternatively:

```
df$day = df$day + 1
```

Comment: You can also use the argument `week_start`: `wday(df$date, label = TRUE, week_start = 1)`

Answer (score 14):

This should do the trick

```
df = data.frame(date=c("2012-02-01", "2012-02-01", "2012-02-02")) 
dow <- function(x) format(as.Date(x), "%A")
df$day <- dow(df$date)
df

#Returns:
        date       day
1 2012-02-01 Wednesday
2 2012-02-01 Wednesday
3 2012-02-02  Thursday
```

Answer (score 10):

```
start = as.POSIXct("2017-09-01")
end = as.POSIXct("2017-09-06")

dat = data.frame(Date = seq.POSIXt(from = start,
                                   to = end,
                                   by = "DSTday"))

# see ?strptime for details of formats you can extract

# day of the week as numeric (Monday is 1)
dat$weekday1 = as.numeric(format(dat$Date, format = "%u"))

# abbreviated weekday name
dat$weekday2 = format(dat$Date, format = "%a")

# full weekday name
dat$weekday3 = format(dat$Date, format = "%A")

dat
# returns
    Date       weekday1 weekday2  weekday3
1 2017-09-01        5      Fri    Friday
2 2017-09-02        6      Sat    Saturday
3 2017-09-03        7      Sun    Sunday
4 2017-09-04        1      Mon    Monday
5 2017-09-05        2      Tue    Tuesday
6 2017-09-06        3      Wed    Wednesday
```

Answer (score 4):

form comment of JStrahl `format(as.Date(df$date),"%w")`, we get number of current day :
`as.numeric(format(as.Date("2016-05-09"),"%w"))`