# Extract weekday from POSIXlt date-time variable

Tags: r, datetime

Super easy question, that somehow I can't figure out by reading the documentation.I am reading in a date/time variable into POSIXlt form as follows:

```
data$date <-strptime(unformatted.date, %m/%d/%Y %H:%M)
```

Then, I am trying to create a factor variable representing the weekday:

```
data$weekday <- as.POSIXlt(data$date, format="%A")
```

This returns a variable that is NA.  Help! (And I apologize if this is something most people can get from the documentation...I really have read around, and can't find the answer).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9216138/find-the-day-of-a-week-in-r

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
ttt<-strptime("07/20/2012 18:00", "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M")
ttt
weekdays(ttt)
#[1] "Friday"
```

This can be found out by reading `?POSIXlt` carefully.

PS: `factor(ttt$hour)`

Comment: Thanks!...and...how would I do hours as well? (into a factor variable)

Answer (score 0):

```
library(lubridate)
ttt<-strptime("01/12/2018 18:00", "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M")
wday(ttt)
[1] 6 #Sunday=1
wday(ttt,label=TRUE)
[1] Fri
```

This approach can save you conversion if you need to work with numbers