# Converting date to a day of week in R

Tags: r

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Find the day of a week in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9216138/find-the-day-of-a-week-in-r)

I have a data for days like 11-01-2011 etc. But I want to add the data corresponding
the date as Monday, Tuesday etc. Is there any R package that contains the information of the dates with days?

Answer (score 69):

```
weekdays(as.Date('16-08-2012','%d-%m-%Y'))
[1] "Thursday"
```

Comment: I always forget that `weekdays()` is in base R. +1

Answer (score 20):

The `lubridate` package is great for this sort of stuff.

```
> wday(as.Date('16-08-2012','%d-%m-%Y'))
[1] 5
> wday(as.Date('16-08-2012','%d-%m-%Y'), label=TRUE)
[1] Thurs
Levels: Sun < Mon < Tues < Wed < Thurs < Fri < Sat
> wday(as.Date('16-08-2012','%d-%m-%Y'), label=TRUE, abbr = FALSE)
[1] Thursday
Levels: Sunday < Monday < Tuesday < Wednesday < Thursday < Friday < Saturday
```

Answer (score 10):

*Here is some information to create your own library or routine*

**Constants:**

**day_of_month**

```
    the day of the month
    e.g. if input mm-dd-yyy then dd
```

**month**:

```
march = 1
april = 2
may = 3
...
```

**year**

```
yy[yy]  (last to digits from yyyy)
   *subtract 1 if month jan or feb
    e.g. if input date is 02-01-2012 (mm-dd-yyyy)
         year =  (12-1) = 11
```

**century**

```
[yy]yy  (first two digits from yyyy)
     e.g. if input year is 2012 then 20 = century
     * year 2000, 1900, ... are 20-1, 19-1 respectively
```

**ALGORITHM**

```
step1: floor(century / 4)

step2: year

step3: floor(year/4)

step4: floor(month*2.6 -0.2)  #this is the leap year correction

step5: day_of_month

step6: add step1...step5

step7: divide by 7  # modulo 7 in codespeak

step8: the remainder is the day of the week
```

**To Interpret Results:**

```
Sun = 0, Mon = 1, Tues = 3, etc..
```

Not a library, but as the public service jingle goes...

"Read: The More you Know"

**Ref: http://www.faqs.org/faqs/sci-math-faq/dayWeek/**