# Avoid warnings from FALSE part of ifelse()

Tags: r, if-statement, metafor

I created a user function that computes Hedges' c() bias correction for *g* (Hedges, 1981). It is directly based on `metafor::.cmicalc()` function from `library(metafor)`. It does this:

```
hedges_c <- function(df) {
  return(exp(lgamma(df / 2) - log(sqrt(df / 2)) - lgamma((df - 1)/2)))
}
```

When applied to a vector containing values <= 1, `lgamma()` generates a warning, because `lgamma(0)` (as well as any negative value) generates `NaN`. So, my solution (and also what `metafor::.cmicalc()` does) was including an `ifelse()` statement:

```
hedges_c <- function(df) {
  cdf <- ifelse(df <= 1, 
                NA,
                exp(lgamma(df / 2) - log(sqrt(df / 2)) - lgamma((df - 1)/2)))
  return(cdf)
}
```

But, and here is the problem I don't seem to find the solution to, it still generates the `warnings()`, even if all the values are correctly rendered as `NA`.

Example:

```
hedges_c(c(0, 0, 20, 14, 0, 0, 0, 0))
#[1]      NA      NA 0.9619445 0.9452877      NA      NA      NA      NA
#Warning messages:
#1: In ifelse(df <= 1, NA, exp(lgamma(df/2) - log(sqrt(df/2)) - lgamma((df -  :
#  value out of range in 'lgamma'
#(...)
```

I understand (e.g., from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13303810/unused-argument-error-in-nested-ifelse-statements)) that the third (`FALSE`) argument of `ifelse()` is evaluated even when the condition is `TRUE` (and inversely if I change the order of the condition and the arguments)... But I simply don't know how to solve that (except maybe for hiding warnings before and after...).

(Note: I also tried `dplyr::case_when()`, but it is exactly the same problem.)

Comment: Did you try to use `if(...) { ... } else { ... }` instead of `ifelse(...,...,...)`?

Comment: @Heikki: Yes, but then it does not work correctly when applied on a vector. `ifelse()` allows it to be vectorized.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm pretty sure the values are calculated regardless, and just subset out by `ifelse`. You could always just apply your function to the valid values and make the rest `NA`:

```
hedges_c <- function(df) {
  ss <- df >= 1

  hc <- function(x) exp(lgamma(x / 2) - log(sqrt(x / 2)) - lgamma((x - 1)/2))

  df[ss]  <- hc(df[ss])
  df[!ss] <- NA
  df
}

hedges_c(c(0, 0, 20, 14, 0, 0, 0, 0))
#[1]        NA        NA 0.9619445 0.9452877        NA        NA        NA        NA
```

Comment: As an answer to your comment to my answer, I believe you are right, I remember having read the source of `ifelse` and I have the impression that it creates both vectors, the `yes` and the `no`, and then subsets. I'm not sure and right now don't have the time but will return to this tomorrow.

Comment: I tested with `casewhen` and it also computes all values

Comment: @Moody_Mudskipper - yep, `case_when` just creates a big list of all the logical outcomes of each comparison and then loops over them looking for the first `TRUE` value. That's why the remainder cases are always `TRUE ~ ...` You can pretty much approximate `case_when` by `cbind`-ing each of the comparisons and calling `max.col(result, "first")`

Comment: You and I were right, the last lines of `ifelse` do subset the vector `ans`.

Answer (score 3):

Try using a different approach. Something like the following.

```
hedges_c <- function(df) {
  cdf <- rep(NA, length(df))
  inx <- df > 1
  cdf[inx] <- exp(lgamma(df[inx] / 2) - log(sqrt(df[inx] / 2)) - lgamma((df[inx] - 1)/2))
  return(cdf)
}

hedges_c(c(0, 0, 20, 14, 0, 0, 0, 0))
#[1]        NA        NA 0.9619445 0.9452877        NA        NA        NA
#[8]        NA
```

And the warnings are gone.