# How can I create a vector containing the days of the week?

Tags: r

I need a vector containing the days of the week very often, but I always type it out:

```
days.of.week <- c("Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday")
```

This is pretty easy because it's short, but there's always the possibility of typos. Is there a way to create a vector containing the days of the week programmatically?

Comment: A nice property of doing this using R functions is that it takes into account the locale, e.g. French weekdays in a French locale.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There you go, the vector of weekdays "Monday", ..., "Sunday":

```
days.of.week <- weekdays(x=as.Date(seq(7), origin="1950-01-01"))
```

Answer (score 15):

One possibility:

```
days.of.week <- weekdays(Sys.Date()+0:6)
```

Always starting on Monday:

```
days.of.week <- weekdays(as.Date(4,"1970-01-01",tz="GMT")+0:6)
```

Or you could just define it as you have, but in your `.Rprofile`, so it's always available on startup.

Comment: Would the vector change depending on what day you run this?

Comment: The order would change, it would always start with the day of the week that it is today.

Comment: Yes, if you want it in order, just change the start date to one that is always Monday.

Answer (score 4):

An alternative is to use `weekdays` with  `ISOdate`:

```
weekdays(ISOdate(1, 1, 1:7))
#[1] "Monday"    "Tuesday"   "Wednesday" "Thursday"  "Friday"    "Saturday"  "Sunday"
```

And to get it in other languages `Sys.setlocale` could be used.

```
Sys.setlocale("LC_TIME", "de_DE.UTF-8")
#[1] "de_DE.UTF-8"

weekdays(ISOdate(1, 1, 1:7))
#[1] "Montag"     "Dienstag"   "Mittwoch"   "Donnerstag" "Freitag"    "Samstag"    "Sonntag"
```

Also its possible to use `format`

```
format(ISOdate(1, 1, 1:7), "%A")
#[1] "Monday"    "Tuesday"   "Wednesday" "Thursday"  "Friday"    "Saturday"  "Sunday"
```

or get abbreviated weekday names

```
format(ISOdate(1, 1, 1:7), "%a")
#weekdays(ISOdate(1, 1, 1:7), TRUE) #Alternative
#[1] "Mon" "Tue" "Wed" "Thu" "Fri" "Sat" "Sun"
```

Comment: I keep coming back to this thread, and just discovered this new answer. Nice.

Answer (score 1):

While the function-based answers are slick,  Joshua's last comment is spot-on.  If you've got a variable you use regularly, either create it in your `.Rprofile` or load it from an `.Rdata` file, using some line in `.Rprofile` like  `load('daysofweek.rdata')` .

Note that changing the first day of the week is as simple as

`neworder <- days.of.week[c(2:7,1)]`

Answer (score -2):

Based on today's date we can also find days of a week

```
weekdays(as.Date(seq(7),origin=Sys.Date() - as.POSIXlt(Sys.Date())$wday ))
 [1] "Monday"    "Tuesday"   "Wednesday" "Thursday"  "Friday"    "Saturday" 
 [7] "Sunday"
```