# Match Days of the Week within an Interval to Create Specific Dates

Tags: r, lubridate

I am working with a data set that has the following structure for its dates:

```
Week  DateStart    DateEnd      Day
1     5-Aug-16     11-Aug-16    Monday
2     12-Aug-16    18-Aug-16    Thursday
```

Where "Week" corresponds to a study week number, "DateStart" and "DateEnd" are the first and last days of that week, and "Day" represents the specific day from within that week. I would like to use the "DateStart", "DateEnd", and "Day" fields to create a new field, "Date", that assigns a specific date to each "Day" that falls within the "DateStart" and "DateEnd" interval.

I've used the %--% operator to turn DateStart and DateEnd into an interval:

```
Week_Interval <- DateStart %--% DateEnd
```

but then I haven't had much luck on figuring out how to match the Day field to a date within the resulting interval. I've tried reading through the lubridate documentation, but it didn't seem like there was anything in there that could specifically solve my problem. I'm hoping someone here might have some experience with this and could help point me in the right direction.

My ideal output would be something like:

```
Week  DateStart    DateEnd      Day        Date
1     5-Aug-16     11-Aug-16    Monday     08-08-2016
2     12-Aug-16    18-Aug-16    Thursday   18-08-2016
```

Where the date follows the standard dd-mm-yyyy format.

Comment: is it acceptsable if there are 2 Mondays between 2 start, and end dates?

Comment: Theoretically, there would not be 2 Mondays between 2 starts and end dates, as the DateStarts all take place on Friday and the DateEnds are all on Thursdays. And yes, I'll show my ideal output in an edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take the difference between the day of the week of `Day` and `DateStart` modulo 7 and add that to the `DateStart`.

No packages are used.

```
dow <- c("Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday")
transform(DF, Date = 
  DateStart + (match(Day, dow) - 1 - as.POSIXlt(DateStart)$wday) %% 7)
```

giving:

```
  Week  DateStart    DateEnd      Day       Date
1    1 2016-08-05 2016-08-11   Monday 2016-08-08
2    2 2016-08-12 2016-08-18 Thursday 2016-08-18
```

### Note 1

An [alternative](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16193549/how-can-i-create-a-vector-containing-the-days-of-the-week) to writing out the days of the week, provided you are in an English locale, is:

```
dow <- weekdays(as.Date("1950-01-01") + 0:6)
```

### Note 2

In the example the Start Date is Friday on both rows. If it were known that that is always the case we could shorten the code by hard coding it as 5:

```
transform(DF, Date = DateStart + (match(Day, dow) - 1 - 5) %% 7)
```

### Note 3

The input, in reproducible form, is:

```
Lines <- "Week  DateStart    DateEnd      Day
1     5-Aug-16     11-Aug-16    Monday
2     12-Aug-16    18-Aug-16    Thursday"
DF <- read.table(text = Lines, header = TRUE)
fmt <- "%d-%b-%y"
DF <- transform(DF, DateStart = as.Date(DateStart, fmt),
  DateEnd = as.Date(DateEnd, fmt))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
# example data
df = read.table(text = "
Week  DateStart    DateEnd      Day
1     5-Aug-16     11-Aug-16    Monday
2     12-Aug-16    18-Aug-16    Thursday
", header=T, stringsAsFactors=F)

library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

df %>%
  group_by(Week, Day) %>%               # for each week and day
  mutate(Date = list(seq(dmy(DateStart), dmy(DateEnd), "1 day")),  # get sequence of dates between start and end
         Day2 = map(Date, weekdays)) %>%                           # get name of days for each date in the sequence
  unnest() %>%                          # unnest dates
  ungroup() %>%                         # forget the grouping
  filter(Day == Day2) %>%               # keep days that match
  select(-Day2)                         # remove unnecessary column

# # A tibble: 2 x 5
#    Week DateStart DateEnd   Day      Date      
#   <int> <chr>     <chr>     <chr>    <date>    
# 1     1 5-Aug-16  11-Aug-16 Monday   2016-08-08
# 2     2 12-Aug-16 18-Aug-16 Thursday 2016-08-18
```