# Trouble with geom_bar

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to create a graph to show the correlation between Minecraft streams/non Minecraft streams and the day of the week for a given streamer.

- The `minecraft` variable is a dummy variable, with either 0 or 1 for all observations.
- The `weekday` variable is categorical, with numbers from 1-7 indicating the day of the week.

This is what I have:

```
streamerData %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=minecraft)) +
  geom_bar(aes(fill=weekday)) +
  theme_ipsum_rc()
```

[image: It's giving me this graph:]

Comment: Can you post the output of `dput(streamerData)`?

Comment: Try `streamerData %>% ggplot(aes(x=as.factor(minecraft), y=weekday)) + geom_dotplot(binaxis = "y", stackdir = "center")`

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Try converting the numerical data for the `weekday` variable into categorical data with some code like this. There may be an easier way to do this but it should work.

```
for (x in 1:high)
{
  if (streamerData$weekday[x] == 1)
  {
    streamerData$weekday[x] = "Sunday"
  }
  else if (streamerData$weekday[x] == 2)
  {
    streamerData$weekday[x] = "Monday"
  }
  else if (streamerData$weekday[x] == 3)
  {
    streamerData$weekday[x] = "Tuesday"
  }
  else if (streamerData$weekday[x] == 4)
  {
    streamerData$weekday[x] = "Wednesday"
  }
  else if (streamerData$weekday[x] == 5)
  {
    streamerData$weekday[x] = "Thursday"
  }
  else if (streamerData$weekday[x] == 6)
  {
    streamerData$weekday[x] = "Friday"
  }
  else if (streamerData$weekday[x] == 7)
  {
    streamerData$weekday[x] = "Saturday"
  }
}
```

`high` should be replaced with whatever the length of your data is. After running this, run what you currently have and it should work.

Comment: yes, there is a better way to do this. Using a for loop and so much repeated code is very inefficient. Not only regarding computing, but also to type and read it. Your entire code can be written as `c("Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday")[streamerData$weekday]` (simple subsetting), or if you prefer not to spell out all days, you can use: `weekdays(ISOdate(1, 1, 1:7))` (https://stackoverflow.com/a/68395524/7941188)

Comment: The code provided in your answer utilises inefficient patterns - both from a performance and readability perspective. Please review common data structures and algorithms and edit your answer.