# Get weekdays in English in R

Tags: r, date, locale, weekday

I am using R outside the US and I got everything working in English, but the result of `weekdays()` is still in Spanish:

```
Day <- seq(as.Date("2013-06-01"), by=1, len=30)
weekdays(Day)
[1] "sábado"    "domingo"   "lunes"     "martes"    "miércoles"  (...)
```

Any ideas on how to get the weekdays in English?

Comment: That is caused by your locale setting in Linux/UNIX Try: (Sys.setenv("LANGUAGE"="En").  I assume the same works in Windows, but I do not know first hand.

Comment: Thank you jim mcnamara, I am using Ubuntu but even after the Sys.setenv I still get the weeekdays() in Spanish!

Comment: I do not have an answer then.  Sorry.

Comment: Does this work: `Sys.setlocale("LC_TIME", "en_US"); weekdays(Sys.Date()+0:6)`?

Comment: Thank you Josh O'Brien, this is what I get:                      Warning message:
In Sys.setlocale("LC_TIME", "en_US") :
  OS reports request to set locale to "en_US" cannot be honored

Comment: Cool. I'll add the *NIX version to my answer.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Printing of `Date` and `POSIX*t` objects seems to be controlled by the `LC_TIME` locale category.

On Windows, you change it like this:

```
## First, save the current value so we can restore it later
Sys.getlocale("LC_TIME")
# [1] "English_United States.1252"

## First in Spanish
Sys.setlocale("LC_TIME","Spanish Modern Sort")
# [1] "Spanish_Spain.1252"
weekdays(Sys.Date()+0:6)
# [1] "lunes"     "martes"    "miércoles" "jueves"    "viernes"   "sábado"   
# [7] "domingo"  

## Then back to (US) English
Sys.setlocale("LC_TIME","English United States")
# [1] "English_United States.1252"
weekdays(Sys.Date()+0:6)
# [1] "Monday"    "Tuesday"   "Wednesday" "Thursday"  "Friday"    "Saturday" 
# [7] "Sunday"
```

On most *NIXes, the equivalent would be:

```
Sys.setlocale("LC_TIME", "en_US")
```

The particular locale names are OS-dependent, as mentioned in `?Sys.setlocale`. For names accepted by Windows, [see here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/goglobal/bb895996.aspx). For names accepted by Linux, [see here](http://www.localeplanet.com/icu/).

Comment: as a restricted user, this doesn't work for me on either windows or linux - "OS reports request ... cannot be honored"

Comment: It may be a different argument to `Sys.setlocale`. On a Mac the back-to-English argument is "en_US.UTF-8".

Comment: Thank you all! I believe this works in Ubuntu:                       > Sys.setlocale("LC_TIME", "C")

Comment: @eddi -- That's just the error message I get when I use an invalid name for the locale...  Out of curiosity, what do you get when you type `Sys.getlocale("LC_TIME")`? 
Also, does this work, or does it give you an error: `Sys.setlocale("LC_TIME", Sys.getlocale("LC_TIME"))`?

Comment: I see, thanks. I don't get an error with that last expression, and my locale on linux is "C" and is "English_United States.1252" on windows. On windows "Spanish Modern Sort" or "Spanish_Modern_Sort" don't work, but e.g. "Spanish_Argentina" works. I guess it has to do with peculiarities of the OS setup.

Answer (score 13):

```
Sys.setlocale("LC_TIME", "C")
```

did the trick for me. Also this don't bring us `OS reports request to set locale to "EN" cannot be honored` error message.

Answer (score 12):

From my [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9216316/967840), you can get weekdays in English without messing with locales like this:

```
c("Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", 
  "Friday", "Saturday")[as.POSIXlt(Day)$wday + 1]
```

Comment: are you sure this isn't locale dependent? the weekday doesn't start on Sunday in all countries

Comment: @eddi, I'm pretty sure because `POSIXlt` is based on [struct tm](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ctime/tm/) and `tm_wday` is "days since Sunday" ... edit: and because `?POSIXlt` says `wday` is "0-6 day of the week, starting on Sunday."

Comment: list_wday_en <- c("Sun", "Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat") wday_now <- list_wday_en[wday(now())]

Answer (score 9):

Under windows RStudio

`Sys.setlocale("LC_TIME", "English")`

That was the only thing that worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

I faced the very same problem trying to change the locale from es_ES to en_US (both UTF-8).

R message is given by R main workspace, as it cannot change system locale. If code is inserted into an R-script a new workspace (the running one) is created, and locale can be overriden.

In my code I included the following lines:

```
curr_locale <- Sys.getlocale("LC_TIME")
Sys.setlocale("LC_TIME","en_US.UTF-8")

#<specific code for graph generation>

Sys.setlocale("LC_TIME",curr_locale)
```

That made the change!

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
dev_null <- Sys.setlocale("LC_TIME", "english")
```

Comment: How does that differ from the answer by @EdgarGithub?

Comment: It will not cause this warning: Warning message: In Sys.setlocale("LC_TIME", "english") : OS reports request to set locale to "en_US" cannot be honored @MrBeanBremen

Answer (score 1):

I personally prefer not to modify `Sys` settings. An alternative solution using the `clock` package would be:

```
Date <- seq(as.Date("2013-06-01"), by = 1, len = 30)

# string representation
as.character(clock::date_weekday_factor(Date))

# factor representation
factor(clock::date_weekday_factor(Date, encoding = "iso"), ordered = F)
```