# Lubridate parse_date_time cant process abbreviated month names in mixture of dates

Tags: r, date, lubridate

I have a data frame column of dates (in character format) with a mixture of dates:

```
("Apr11", "2005-01-01", "Apr13", "2009-12-01")
```

I tried to use the lubridate parse_date_time() function to parse these dates as follows:

```
parse_date_time(x = variable, orders = c('y-m-d', 'by'), locale='en_US.UTF-8')
```

While **parse_date_time()** is able to parse dates with the format 'y-m-d', it fails to parse dates with the format 'by'.

I then tried to experiment with a toy example but with no success:

```
z <- "Apr11"
parse_date_time(z,"by")
```

I keep getting the same error:

```
[1] NA
Warning message:
All formats failed to parse. No formats found.
```

I read the documentation and tried a number of different things with no luck:

- I set locale to the **default_locale()** function.
- I tried B instead of b
- I tried setting setting the exact option to True as given by the note in the documentation
- I tried the **parse_date_time2()** function which worked on the toy example, but didn't work on the original dataframe with the mixture of dates (This threw a warning message -  Multiple orders supplied. Only first order is used.)

I realize that b is locale sensitive but I don't see the issue here - Here's the output from **default_locale()**

```
<locale>
Numbers:  123,456.78
Formats:  %AD / %AT
Timezone: UTC
Encoding: UTF-8
<date_names>
Days:   Sunday (Sun), Monday (Mon), Tuesday (Tue), Wednesday (Wed), Thursday (Thu), Friday (Fri), Saturday (Sat)
Months: January (Jan), February (Feb), March (Mar), April (Apr), May (May), June (Jun), July (Jul), August (Aug), September (Sep),
    October (Oct), November (Nov), December (Dec)
AM/PM:  AM/PM
```

And here's the output from **Sys.getlocale()**

```
[1] "LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8;LC_NUMERIC=C;LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8;LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8;LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8;LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8;LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8;LC_NAME=C;LC_ADDRESS=C;LC_TELEPHONE=C;LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8;LC_IDENTIFICATION=C"
```

I've also looked into various posts on stackoverflow but nothing helped:

- [Changing date format in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7439977/changing-date-format-in-r)
- [How to change multiple Date formats in same column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13764514/how-to-change-multiple-date-formats-in-same-column)
- [convert variable with mixed date formats to one format in r](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25463523/convert-variable-with-mixed-date-formats-to-one-format-in-r)
- [Why R package lubridate can't parse vector with multiple formats?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30338735/why-r-package-lubridate-cant-parse-vector-with-multiple-formats/33452653)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think the problem is you are not supplying a day - try for example `parse_date_time("1Apr11","dby")`

Comment: but parse_date_time2() works without supplying the day - am not sure if this would change anything.

Comment: Good point, I am not sure why this is, the two parsers must be doing something slightly different under the hood. But the problem is parsing this individual date, not the vector, try e.g. `parse_date_time(c("1Apr11", "2015-05-10"), c("dby", "Y-m-d"))` - I suppose I didn't understand your original question and thought it was about vectorizing it rather than parsing that particular string

Comment: Thanks! I initially tried parse_date_time2() which didn't work but  parse_date_time works as suggested. I just need to append 1 to the dataset - wish I could avoid doing this

Comment: This could be a bug in `parse_date_time` actually. Could be worth checking with the developers by raising an issue at https://github.com/tidyverse/lubridate/issues