# How to determine if date is a weekend or not (not using lubridate)

Tags: r, datetime, lubridate

I have a vector of date objects (`yyyy-mm-dd`) and I want to determine if any of them are on weekend or not. Is there a function that can determine this straightaway?

I can use `wday()` in the **lubridate** package and then determine if returned value is `01` or `07`, but anything else more straightforward?

```
x <- seq(Sys.Date()-10, Sys.Date(), by = 1)
x[lubridate::wday(x) %in% c(1, 7)]
```

Comment: `is.weekend` from "cron"?

Comment: Why is the `lubridate` approach not straight forward?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9216138/find-the-day-of-a-week-in-r

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I put @AnandaMahto's suggestion here rather than a comment:

```
library(chron)
x <- seq(Sys.Date()-10, Sys.Date(), by = 1)
x[is.weekend(x)]

## [1] "2014-10-11" "2014-10-12" "2014-10-18"
```

Comment: @ConstanzaGarcia Can you make this reproducible?  You add a desparaging comment that can't be tested that may push others away from a correct answer.  Conversely, you may be correct, if so I'd delete the answer or update it accordingly.  I suspect you have something off in your data types that's causing the issue but would like to get to the problem (this answer or your data) either way.  May I suggest you delete this comment and open a new question with your data that  demonstrates the problem (a reproducible example) and then link back to this question/answer.

Answer (score 32):

You can use the base R function `weekdays()`.

```
x <- seq(Sys.Date() - 10, Sys.Date(), by = 1)
weekdays(x, abbr = TRUE)
# [1] "Wed" "Thu" "Fri" "Sat" "Sun" "Mon" "Tue" "Wed" "Thu" "Fri" "Sat"
x[grepl("S(at|un)", weekdays(x))]
# [1] "2014-10-11" "2014-10-12" "2014-10-18"
```

As far as *lubridate* goes, `wday()` has a `label` argument.  When set to `TRUE`, the (abbreviated) day names are returned instead of numbers. Use the `abbr` argument to change to full names.

```
library(lubridate)
wday(x, label = TRUE)
# [1] Wed   Thurs Fri   Sat   Sun   Mon   Tues  Wed   Thurs Fri   Sat  
# Levels: Sun < Mon < Tues < Wed < Thurs < Fri < Sat
```

Answer (score 11):

Another approach could be to use `format` and `%u`, which gives a number for the day of the week, starting with "1" representing "Monday".

With that, you can do:

```
x <- seq(as.Date("2014-10-18")-10, Sys.Date(), by = 1)
format(x, "%u") %in% c(6, 7)
#  [1] FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
x[format(x, "%u") %in% c(6, 7)]
# [1] "2014-10-11" "2014-10-12" "2014-10-18"
```

Comment: Luckily, there is also `%w` that maps Sunday to `0`. So we can all live in peace. `data.frame(a = format(x, "%a"), u = format(x, "%u"), w = format(x, "%w"))`.

Answer (score 6):

Using lubridate to avoid other packages, you can use:

```
is_weekday = function(timestamp){
  lubridate::wday(timestamp, week_start = 1) < 6
}
```

Answer (score 5):

The `wday` in both `lubridate` and `data.table` (yes, `data.table` has pretty much everything but the kitchen sink :-) both do a variation on:

```
as.POSIXlt(x, tz = tz(x))$wday + 1 # lubridate
as.POSIXlt(x)$wday + 1L            # data.table
```

So you could, in theory, just do:

```
as.POSIXlt("2014-10-18")$wday + 1
## [1] 7
```

and then test for the weekend days as other answer(s) do.

Comment: **Note:** `c(1,2,3,4,5)` is weekday. `c(6,0)` is the weekend when you do `as.POSIXlt("2014-10-18")$wday`

Answer (score 3):

After looking a lot about this topic, I found this solution particularly simple using the package RQuantLib

```
install.packages("RQuantLib")
library(RQuantLib)
isBusinessDay(calendar="WeekendsOnly", dates=yourdatesofinterest)
```

You can modify this code with different calendars to add to the weekends different sets of holidays in different countries (below just an example, but they have many more).

```
isBusinessDay(calendar="UnitedStates", dates=yourdatesofinterest)
isBusinessDay(calendar="UnitedStates/Settlement", dates=yourdatesofinterest)
isBusinessDay(calendar="UnitedStates/NYSE", dates=yourdatesofinterest)
isBusinessDay(calendar="Sweden", dates=yourdatesofinterest)
isBusinessDay(calendar="Mexico", dates=yourdatesofinterest)
```

I hope it helps somebody

Comment: This is SUCH an underrated answer.  Many thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You could use `isWeekend` from [package timeDate](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/timeDate/index.html). Hard to do more straightforward :). `wday` specify which days should be considered as weekdays. By default from Mondays to Fridays.

```
> today <- isWeekend(Sys.Date(), wday = 1:5)
if (as.logical(today)){
  print("YES")
} else print("NO")
```

From the documentation :

```
## Dates in April, currentYear:
   currentYear = getRmetricsOptions("currentYear")
   tS = timeSequence(
      from = paste(currentYear, "-03-01", sep = ""),
      to = paste(currentYear, "-04-30", sep = ""))
   tS

## Subset of Weekends:
   isWeekend(tS)
   tS[isWeekend(tS)]
```

It works also with `isWeekday`.