# how to convert the weekdays to a factor in R

Tags: r, date

I have a data frame like this:

```
date          count   wd
2012-10-01        0  Monday
2012-10-02        5  Tuesday
2012-10-06       10  Saturday
2012-10-07       15  Sunday
```

I use

```
dat <- mutate(dat,wd = weekdays(as.Date(dat$date)))
```

to add a new array "wd" , however, I'd like to add a new factor array to show if this day is a weekday or weekend, something like:

```
date          count   wd
2012-10-01        0  weekday
2012-10-02        5  weekday
2012-10-06       10  weekend
2012-10-07       15  weekend
```

Is any simple way to do that? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ifelse` is that standard way to check a condition on each element of a vector and do something based on the check. Since you already have the named weekdays, you have a pretty trivial condition to check:

```
dat$we = ifelse(dat$wd %in% c("Saturday", "Sunday"), "weekend", "weekday")
```

This adds a new variable, `we`, to your data. It will be a factor by default when added to the data frame with `$<-`.

You can, of course, use `ifelse()` inside `mutate` (or use `dplyr::if_else`), in which case you would need to wrap the result in `factor()` to coerce it to a factor - it will be a `character` by otherwise.

---

For other methods of checking weekendness that don't depend on already having the names of the days of the week see [How to check if a date is a weekend?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26441700/903061).