# Minute Sequence through days

Tags: r

Want to create a seq of minutes from starting date to end date, but leave out Saturday and Sunday in the output.

I can create the sequence, but don't know how to leave out saturdays and sundays..

And also do not want the seconds part in the output, as well as the "IST" part.

```
seq.POSIXt( as.POSIXct( "2019/06/21"), as.POSIXct( "2019/06/30"), "min")
```

If there is any other function or method to do it any faster, or simpler, would be much appreciated. TIA

Comment: Several options here for identifying weekends / weekdays - https://stackoverflow.com/a/26441992/496803 - e.g. `s[!format(s,"%u") %in% c(6,7)]` from over there which will get rid of Saturday/Sunday.

Comment: newbie, and am in a hurry, will do my searching next time around. thanks..

Answer (score 1):

Using the library timeDate helps things:

```
library(timeDate)

have = seq.POSIXt( as.POSIXct( "2019/06/21"), as.POSIXct( "2019/06/30"), "min")
want = have[isWeekday(have)]
```

Answer (score 0):

After generating the sequence, you can use `weekdays` to filter out days other than Saturday and Sunday and then `format` to get output in desired format.

```
all_time <- seq.POSIXt( as.POSIXct( "2019/06/21"), as.POSIXct( "2019/06/30"), "min")
format(all_time[!weekdays(all_time) %in% c("Saturday", "Sunday")], "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")
# [1] "2019-06-21 00:00" "2019-06-21 00:01" "2019-06-21 00:02" "2019-06-21 00:03" 
#     "2019-06-21 00:04" "2019-06-21 00:05" "2019-06-21 00:06" "2019-06-21 00:07" 
#     "2019-06-21 00:08" "2019-06-21 00:09" ......
```

As @thelatemail points out that `weekdays` is locale-dependent and the above would not work if you have non-English locale. We can instead use weekday to remove weekends.

```
format(all_time[!format(all_time, "%u") %in% c(6, 7)], "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")
```

Comment: Might be problematic as `weekdays` is locale-dependent - using a format that spits out a consistent numeric label like `%u` or `%w` is probably safer.

Comment: @thelatemail yes, right. Updated the answer with that.

Comment: Thank you Mr.Shah, exactly to the point.