# Convert a date to a day number (monday = 1, tuesday = 2) in R

Tags: r, date, numbers, rstudio, type-conversion

Can someone help me with the following:

I have a date, for example: 3-1-2014,

And I would like to convert this to the number 5, because it is a friday.

So 7-1-2014 would be 1, because it is a monday.

Which package/code can do this for me?

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Find the day of a week in R](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9216138/find-the-day-of-a-week-in-r)

Comment: i'm pretty sure this is a duplicate, but you can use POSIXlt, in base R to transform a date to a weekday number. `as.POSIXlt('2015-03-01')$wday`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can do this easily with `lubridate` although it indexes Sunday as '1'.  So since March 1, 2014 was a Saturday it would return '7'

```
library(lubridate)
wday(mdy("3-1-2014"))
[1] 7
```

Comment: This is shifted by one. The question was asking for Saturday = 6, not Saturday = 7

Answer (score 8):

Using R base, you can use `strftime` function with "%u" format parameter to return the weekday.

```
as.numeric(strftime(as.Date('3-1-2014', "%d-%m-%Y"), "%u"))
[1] 5
```

Answer (score 2):

Now you can use  `week_start` option with `wday()`

> day on which week starts following ISO conventions - 1 means Monday, 7
>   means Sunday (default). You can set lubridate.week.start option to
>   control this parameter globally.

So following code gives desired output

```
library(lubridate) 
lubridate::wday(mdy("3-1-2014"), week_start = 1)
[1] 6
```

Please note that `data.table` library has function with the same name `wday()` but without `week_start` option.

Answer (score 1):

Using the package "lubridate" is pretty much the answer. It indexes Sunday as '1' and Saturday as '6', but you can simply shift one day by showing the day of week number of the prior day like this:

```
library(lubridate) 
wday(mdy("3-1-2014") -1)
[1] 6
```