# Add a variable including the day of the week

Tags: r, date, variables

This could seem a repetition but I haven't found this exact question's answer yet.
I have this *dataframe*:

```
  Day.of.the.month    Month Year   Items Amount.in.euros
1                1  January 2005 Nothing            0.00
2                2 February 2008    Food            7.78
3                3    April 2009 Nothing            0.00
4                4  January 2016     Bus            2.00
```

I want to create a column named "day.of.the.week" including, of course, "saturday", "sunday" and so on. If the date was formatted as '2012/02/02' I would not have probs, but this way I don't know whether there is a way nor a workaround to solve the issue.

Any hint?

Comment: Check out `lubridate` package. It has everything you need

Comment: you can format your data into a date column with: `df$date <- as.Date(
  paste0(df$Day.of.the.month,df$Month,df$Year),
  format = '%d%B%Y')`

Comment: Related or possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9216138/find-the-day-of-a-week

Comment: @zx8754 the problem mentioned in this questions seems to be more about formatting text to a date than getting a weekday from the resulting date

Comment: @Ape Thanks, that is why didn't close the post. Just added a link to a related post.

Answer (score 4):

Do you want this?

```
options(stringsAsFactors = F)
df <- data.frame( x = c(1, 2, 3, 4) ,y = c("January", "February","April", "January"), z = c(2005, 2008, 2009, 2016))

weekdays(as.Date(paste0(df$x, df$y, df$z),"%d%B%Y")) # %d for date, %B for month in complete and %Y for year complete
```

---

**This is just a side note**

**Note**: Since someone commented that this solution is being locale dependent. So if that is the case you can always do "`Sys.setlocale("LC_TIME", "C")`" to change your locale settings also, use `Sys.getlocale()` to get your locale settings.

If someone interested in making this permanent while starting the R session everytime:

You can also write below script on your `.RProfile` file (which is usually located at your home directory , in windows it is mostly found at Documents folder):

```
.First <- function() {
   Sys.setlocale("LC_TIME", "C")
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Day.of.the.month<-as.numeric(c(1,2,3,4))
Month<-as.character(c("January","February","April","January"))
Year<-as.numeric(c(2005,2008,2009,2016))
Items<-as.character(c("Nothing","Food","Nothing","Bus"))
Amount.in.euros<-as.numeric(c(0.00,7.78,0.0,2.0))
complete.date<-paste(Year,Month,Day.of.the.month)
strptime(complete.date, "%Y %B %d")
example1.data <- 
data.frame(Day.of.the.month,Month,Year,Items,Amount.in.euros,complete.date)
example1.data$weekday <- weekdays(as.Date(example1.data$complete.date))
```

Comment: Why do you load `lubridate` if you do not call any function from the package?

Comment: you don't need, all functions are from base package. Sorry