# How do I check if a date is between two values in R?

Tags: r

I have a table that looks like this;

```
user_id     timestamp
aa          2018-01-01 12:01 UTC
ab          2018-01-01 05:01 UTC
bb          2018-06-01 09:01 UTC
bc          2018-03-03 23:01 UTC
cc          2018-01-02 11:01 UTC
```

I have another table that has every week in 2018.

```
week_id    week_start     week_end
1          2018-01-01     2018-01-07
2          2018-01-08     2018-01-15
3          2018-01-16     2018-01-23
4          2018-01-23     2018-01-30
...        ...            ...
```

Assume the week_start is a Monday and week_end is a Sunday.

I'd like to do two things. I'd first like to join the week_id to the first table and then I'd like to assign a day to each of the timestamps. My output would look like this:

```
user_id     timestamp               week_id    day_of_week
aa          2018-01-01 12:01 UTC    1          Monday
ab          2018-01-02 05:01 UTC    1          Tuesday
bb          2018-01-13 09:01 UTC    2          Friday
bc          2018-01-28 23:01 UTC    4          Friday
cc          2018-01-06 11:01 UTC    1          Saturday
```

In Excel I could easily do this with a `vlookup`. My main interest is to learn how to join tables in cases like this. For that reason, I won't accept answers that use the `weekday` function.

Here are both of the tables in a more accessible format.

```
user_id <- c("aa", "ab", "bb", "bc", "cc")
timestamp <- c("2018-01-01 12:01", "2018-01-01 05:01", "2018-06-01 09:01", "2018-03-03 23:01", "2018-01-02 11:01")

week_id <- seq(1,52)
week_start <- seq(as.Date("2018-01-01"), as.Date("2018-12-31"), 7)
week_end <- week_start + 6

week_start <- week_start[1:52]
week_end <- week_end[1:52]  

table1 <- data.frame(user_id, timestamp)
table2 <- data.frame(week_id, week_start, week_end)
```

Comment: As commented on your last version, please do share the data with `dput`---it makes it copy/pasteable and confirms you are using the appropriate classes. (The timestamp data is particularly annoying to import as you've shared it without delimiters or quotes. `dput(head(your_sample_data))` is much friendlier.)

Comment: I'd also recommend removing the `day_of_week` component from this question. It's entirely separate from your "main interest" in learning how to join these tables. Better to ask it as a separate question. [Or maybe search for it separately](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9216138/903061) before asking.

Comment: `format(Sys.time(), format="%U %a %A")` returns `"12 Mon Monday"`, so it seems that instead of trying to find intervals, you could just convert each date into your `week_id` directly. So, `format(x$timestamp, format="%U")` and `format(x$timestamp, format="%A")` might give you what you need, no joins.

Comment: If you've got requirements for what answers you won't accept, if would be easier to help with a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) and at least a sense of what you've tried so far

Answer (score 1):

Using SQL one can join two tables on a range like this.  This seems the most elegant solution expressing our intent directly but we also provide some alternatives further below.

```
library(sqldf)

DF1$date <- as.Date(DF1$timestamp)

sqldf("select * 
  from DF1 a 
  left join DF2 b on date between week_start and week_end")
```

giving:

```
  user_id           timestamp       date week_id week_start   week_end
1      aa 2018-01-01 12:01:00 2018-01-01       1 2018-01-01 2018-01-07
2      ab 2018-01-01 05:01:00 2018-01-01       1 2018-01-01 2018-01-07
3      bb 2018-06-01 09:01:00 2018-06-01      NA       <NA>       <NA>
4      bc 2018-03-03 23:01:00 2018-03-04      NA       <NA>       <NA>
5      cc 2018-01-02 11:01:00 2018-01-02       1 2018-01-01 2018-01-07
```

### dplyr

In a comment the poster asked for whether it could be done in dplyr. It can't be done directly since dplyr does not support complex joins but a workaound would be to do a full cross join of the two data frames which gives rise to an `nrow(DF1) * nrow(DF2)` intermediate result and then filter this down.  dplyr does not directly support cross joins but we can simulate one by doing a full join on an identical dummy constant column that is appended to both data frames in the full join. Since we actually need a right join here to add back the unmatched rows, we do a final right join with the original `DF1` data frame.  Obviously this is entirely impractical for sufficiently large inputs but for the small input here we can do it.  If it were known that there is a match in `DF2` to every row in `DF1` then the `right_join` at the end could be omitted.

```
DF1 %>% 
  mutate(date = as.Date(timestamp), dummy = 1) %>%
  full_join(DF2 %>% mutate(dummy = 1)) %>%
  filter(date >= week_start & date <= week_end) %>%
  select(-dummy) %>%
  right_join(DF1)
```

### R Base

`findix` finds the index in `DF2` corresponding to a date `d`. We then `sapply` it over the dates corresponding to rows of `DF1` and put `DF1` and the corresponding `DF2` row together.

```
findix <- function(d) c(which(d >= DF2$week_start & d <= DF2$week_end), NA)[1]
cbind(DF1, DF2[sapply(as.Date(DF1$timestamp), findix), ])
```

### Note

The input data in reproducible form used is:

```
Lines1 <- "user_id     timestamp
aa          2018-01-01 12:01 UTC
ab          2018-01-01 05:01 UTC
bb          2018-06-01 09:01 UTC
bc          2018-03-03 23:01 UTC
cc          2018-01-02 11:01 UTC"
DF1 <- read.csv(text = gsub("     +", ",", Lines1), strip.white = TRUE)
DF1$timestamp <- as.POSIXct(DF1$timestamp)

Lines2 <- "week_id    week_start     week_end
1          2018-01-01     2018-01-07
2          2018-01-08     2018-01-15
3          2018-01-16     2018-01-23
4          2018-01-23     2018-01-30"
DF2 <- read.table(text = Lines2, header = TRUE)
DF2$week_start <- as.Date(DF2$week_start)
DF2$week_end <- as.Date(DF2$week_end)
```

Comment: This is great, thank you. Is it possible to do this with the joins available in `dplyr`?

Comment: I don't think dplyr supports complex joins directly but I have added an example of doing it using a workaround.  Note that this may be impractical given that it creates a huge intermediate result.

Answer (score 0):

This is a case for the `fuzzyjoin`-package. With the `match_fun`- argument we can specify conditions for each column. In this case `table1$date >= table2$week_start` and `table1$date <= table2$week_end`.

```
library(fuzzyjoin)
library(lubridate)

table1$date <- as.Date(table1$timestamp)

fuzzy_left_join(table1, table2, 
                by = c("date" = "week_start", "date" = "week_end"),
                match_fun = list(`>=`, `<=`)) %>%
  mutate(day_of_week = wday(date, label = TRUE)) %>%
  select(user_id, timestamp, week_id, day_of_week) 

  user_id        timestamp week_id day_of_week
1      aa 2018-01-01 12:01       1          Mo
2      ab 2018-01-01 05:01       1          Mo
3      bb 2018-06-01 09:01      22          Fr
4      bc 2018-03-03 23:01       9          Sa
5      cc 2018-01-02 11:01       1          Di
```

I'm also a smartass because I didn't use the `weekday`-function but wday from the `lubridate`-package.