# Day of week in R

Tags: r, weekday

I have a date in R and it's formatted as follows:

2018-08-31 01:00:00

Is there any way in R to add another column with the day of the week associated with the date? My dataset is very large.

Comment: `weekdays(as.Date("2018-08-31 01:00:00"))`?

Comment: This is a duplicate question, an earlier answer can be found [Find the day of  a week](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9216316/1444043).

Comment: The problem is that in the column of the date I have the date (2018-08-31) and the hour, minute and second  (01:00:00) as you can see above. The format of my date is different from the question you mentioned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will probably do the trick for you.
Experiment with different settings of the `label`- and `abbr`-arguments to get the derised results.

```
library(lubridate)
lubridate::wday( as.POSIXct( "2018-08-31 01:00:00", 
                             format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S "), 
                 label = TRUE, 
                 abbr = FALSE )
```