# Creating a day of the week variable in R from 'YYYYMMDD'

Tags: r

I have my dates formatted as 'YYYYMMDD' like '20150531' but now I want to separate my data into categories for the 7 days of the week by creating another variable called Day. How could I do this in R?

Comment: From package `lubridate`:  `wday(as_date("20201123"))`

Comment: Related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9216138/find-the-day-of-a-week

Comment: @DanY Thank you very much! :)

Comment: @Henry Thank you very much! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try `weekdays()` function from `base R`:

```
#Data
df <- data.frame(Date='2015031',stringsAsFactors = F)
df$Weekday <- weekdays(as.Date(df$Date,'%Y%m%d'))
```

Output:

```
df
     Date Weekday
1 2015031  Sunday
```

Comment: Thank you very much! :)

Comment: @Lily Always a pleasure dear :)

Answer (score 0):

We can convert to `Date` class and then use `format` to get the weekday name in `base R`

```
df1$Weekday <- format(as.Date(df1$date , '%Y%m%d'), '%a')
```

-output

```
df1
#     date Weekday
#1 2015031     Sun
```

#### data

```
df1 <- data.frame(date = '2015031')
```